# how to put if contains condition inside Angular ng Class

Tags: angular

i have to apply a class conditionally to my grid row but my condition is if the field includes the experission i  want,something like this:

```
<[ngClass]="eventlogs.m_event_log_description.indexOf('SYSTEM_LOG') ? 'logSystem':'logSystem'">
```

but seems it does not work like this, because I don't see any change in my grid color, any idea? should i use indexOf like this?

Comment: `indexOf('SYSTEM_LOG') > -1`

Comment: Or better: `includes('SYSTEM_LOG')`

Comment: i get an error Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined ,strange because the name of my field is m_event_log_description @julianobrasil

Comment: Well... two advices: you shouldn't make your template dirty with long lines of logic like that. If that's unavoidable, use conditional chaining (elvis) operators: `eventlogs?.m_event_log_description?.includes('SYSTEM_LOG')`

Comment: @julianobrasil thanks for the comment to avoid writing like this,whats the alternative in cases like this?to write cleaner?

Comment: If that property is kind of dynamic (for example, that logic is part of a `*ngFor` loop and `eventLogs` is different on each iteration, then you should build a [custom pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#creating-pipes-for-custom-data-transformations). Otherwise, if that's a single piece of data, just create a property in the class behind the template, containing the result of that logic (I'd recommend using observables/async pipe for that, but it can be overwhelming/intimidating if you're not used to them).

Answer (score 1):

To debug this try this:

```
<[ngClass]="onClass()">

onclass(){
  debugger;
  let index = eventlogs.m_event_log_description.indexOf('SYSTEM_LOG');
  if(index) 
  {
    return 'logSystem'
  } 
  return 'logSystem'
 }
```

Hover over eventlogs.  It should not be null or undefined.
Then hover over the m_event_log_description it too should not be null or undefined.

What do you see?